# kotlin let is allowing null object to be handle

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapping

I have created a function to map an object to another as below:

```
        val clothes = items.map { item ->
                                item.material?.let { material ->
                                    Mapper.fromRetrofitResponseToObjectEntity(
                                        material,
                                        item
                                    )
                                }
                            }
```

I have a `NullPointerException` happening on `object.getStatus()`. Checking the logcat of my Android app, `material` is effectively `null` I do not understand why the code inside `item.material.let` is not preventing it as `item.material` is null.

Comment: I can't see how that's possible from your code above. Maybe something internal to the `fromRetrofitResponseToObjectEntity` is not using the reference you think it is. Is the `object.getStatus()` a line of code inside that function?

Comment: Add the exception and `fromRetrofitResponseToObjectEntity` with question .. try not to name a property `object` it makes no sense ..

Comment: @adm I replace the real name by `object`

Comment: @Tenfour04 `object` is null. I saw it in the log

Comment: You can add Some minimal code with which we can reproduce the issue .. can't say much right now with the given code snippet

Comment: We need to see the code where you're checking the log. The code that's causing your problem is somewhere else, like maybe inside `fromRetrofitResponseToObjectEntity()`. Your use of the word `object` is confusing because it's a hard keyword that's not allowed for variable or parameter names.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I printed the variable `item` into the logcat and then I saw that `material` was null. `item` is a JSON object and the field `material` is not present in it when received from the api call.

Comment: Is it true `null` or the String literal `"null"` at the time you log it? You can find out by debugging instead of just logging. Again, it's impossible to really tell what's wrong without seeing more code.